# Подскажите компонент для хранения (буферизации) данных из БД SQLite

Tags: delphi, firedac

Есть база данных SQLite для подключения к которой использую Delphi XE8 и FireDAC. Нужно запросить данные из трех таблиц бд и сохранить в три переменные для последующей обработки, но мой код каждый раз перезаписывает данные.

Я пробовал копировать данные в разные FDMemTable, добавлял для каждой таблицы свой FDQuery, но по непонятным мне причинам данные каждый раз перезаписываются ответом на последний запрос. Как мне отвязать переменные с ответом сервера от FDQuery?

Вот нарисовал схему того как должно работать, для большей наглядности:

[image: Схема получения данных из БД]

Вот мой код:

```pascal
  FDConnection:=TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  FDConnection.DriverName:='SQLite';
  FDConnection.LoginPrompt:=False;
  FDConnection.FormatOptions.MapRules.Add(dtWideMemo, dtWideString);

  dbPages:=TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
  dbFields:=TFDMemTable.Create(nil);

  PageQuery:=TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  PageQuery.Connection:=FDConnection;
  FieldQuery:=TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FieldQuery.Connection:=FDConnection;

  FDConnection.Params.Database:='C:\Users\Wizard\Desktop\project1.db';
  FDConnection.Connected:=True;

  PageQuery.Open('SELECT * FROM pages');
  dbPages.Data:=PageQuery.Data;  

  FieldQuery.Open('SELECT * FROM fields');
  dbFields.Data:=FieldQuery.Data;
```

Код рабочий, подскажите, вот такая конструкция по идее связывает FieldQuery и dbFields:

```pascal
dbFields.Data:=FieldQuery.Data;
```

когда я делаю другой запрос в FieldQuery данные в dbFields тоже перезаписываются. Как одноразово передать данные из FieldQuery в dbFields?

Comment: Наверное, вначале надо разобраться, почему у вас `SELECT` ничего не возвращает. Пустая БД?

Comment: А если отвечать на вопрос из заголовка, то вы уже выбрали правильный компонент - это `TFDMemTable`.

Comment: zed, Да вы правы, была ошибка в другом месте. Подскажите пожалуйста как передать данные из FDQuery в FDMemTable без связывания компонентов. Чтобы можно было использовать FDMemTable как переменную для хранения конкретной выборки.

Comment: Попробуйте метод [CopyDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.CopyDataSet). Хотя, должно и присвоение Data работать. Возможно, не хватает вызова `PageQuery.FetchAll;` перед присвоением (см. [пример в доках](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Data)).

Comment: Спасибо, метод CopyDataSet прекрасно подошел.